# Does Application Insights consider thread scheduling when timing dependencies?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

In the Azure portal the Application Insights blade reports dependency timings per request which it has automatically timed by itself.

Do these timings take into account any time waiting for its return thread to be scheduled by the scheduler?

The reason I ask is that I have a .NET Core microservice (1) using async/await to make calls to another .NET Core microservice (2). Very high timings are being reported by Application Insights as a "dependency" timing in (1), whereas the timings reported as a "request" at (2) are much lower. It's possible that the server was under load at the time. Would load that causes high thread contention cause these "dependency" timings to be higher than expected?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Dependency timing are measured end-to-end, so for example if you had high network latency that would also reflect in the dependency measurement.
Since dependency is measured in the caller, it stands to reason that if there isn't a thread available to complete the timing measurement - the measurement will increase